# Why Clip-path, perspective & linear-gradient on font not works on IE11 / Edge

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to make some polygon, rotate animation effect and gradient on fonts. Chrome and Firefox works fine but internet explorer 11 not working properly. I'm Working on SASS.
I've done some research tried some example but non of that worked.
I've having certain issue on IE/11.

- Prospective property  (Included prefix /
  not working)
- clip-path: polygon not working
- linear-gradient not working on font

  ```
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #bd74c2, #69306D);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -ms-background-clip: text;
  ```

Here is my code [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DayOne/1k9jnb8r/)

In my research it says some of this property will work on IE10+ but im having issue on IE11. Is there another way to work on these property's.

Comment: perspective should work, clip-path is only supported on svg elements (and with url() syntax) and background-clip is only supported since Edge 12.

Comment: Perspective didn't work at all, is there another way to use background-clip.

Answer (score 1):

The problem on IE11 is that `-ms-background-clip: text` wont work. 
More info can be found on the caniuse website:

> Firefox, Chrome and Safari support the unofficial
>   -webkit-background-clip: text (only with prefix)

Ref: https://caniuse.com/#search=background-clip

Your options on IE11 would be for your font to fall back to a flat colour (graceful degradation), Using an svg instead as [DayOne](http:///users/7680307/dayone) suggested or to replace the text with an image on that browser (seriously old-school)

Comment: Seems Work on SVG instead of using clip-path polygon is better option for IE9+ , concerned your point

Comment: Fair point. I edited the comment to include your suggestion although I still would consider this an Image substitution.